# What type of plug is this (looks like mini din 4 pin)

Tags: connector, identification

I'm holding a connector that looks just like a 4-pin mini din male plug, except that the plastic prong is in the wrong place and there is an extra metal strip, wide, thin and too short to be a pin, where the standard mini din plastic prong should be.

It is used to connect the pedals to the main body in my Korg EC310 digital piano.

[image: unknown connector]

[image: different angle]

[image]

Comment: Are you in a concrete building? My psychic powers seem to be too weak today to have a look at the plug, maybe put it outside so I can try again?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Sorry about that. Pics added.

Comment: Can you give us a photo of the outside of the plug too?

Comment: @Will It was shredded and in the garbage, but I recovered it for you. Here you go.

Comment: Might be compaitble with an s-video connector as its a mini din with a flat blade where yours is.  No lump in the middle though

Comment: @Will The plastic prong in the mini din won't go into the socket this thing is designed for. I suppose I could saw it off, but that would compromise the long-term health of the pins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a lot simpler than I thought.

That horizontal metal tab is not a tab, but a bent pin, only it was so bent that only after removing the plug shell were we able to see it.

The plug is a plain old 5-pin mini-DIN.